# Oracle:Set default value for number column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How can we set default value for a number typed column has '00'?I tried this but it still saved it has '0',I need to do this.

```
//alter table table_name add column column1 default '00';
```

Please suggest a way for me.

Comment: I seriously doubt you can store 00 as number data type of a table.

Comment: @Polppan:How to do?I tried it,it`s not working.

Comment: I guess you may have to store as varchar2 or store as number and when you retrieve you do the manipulation in select statement.

Comment: You want to store as number or varchar2?

Comment: You can store as number and create a view while fetching.

Comment: `'00'` is not a number. It's a character literal with two characters. `0` would be a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to store numbers like that - In a format you have described ('00'). You can store numbers as numbers (as values of numeric data type of course) and use `to_char` function or `to_char` function combined with `lpad` function to represent numbers in a format you like. Here is an example:

```
SQL> create table TB_SingleNumberColumn(
  2    col number
  3  )
  4  /

Table created
SQL> insert into TB_SingleNumberColumn(Col) values(1);

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into TB_SingleNumberColumn(Col) values(5);

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into TB_SingleNumberColumn(Col) values(11);

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into TB_SingleNumberColumn(Col) values(111);

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

-- The values as they are
SQL> select * from TB_SingleNumberColumn;

       COL
----------
         1
         5
        11
       111

-- Values padded with zeros.
SQL> select to_char(col, '000') res 
  2   from TB_SingleNumberColumn;

RES
----
 001
 005
 011
 111 

SQL> select lpad(to_char(col), 3, '0')
  2    from TB_SingleNumberColumn
  3  ;

LPAD(TO_CHAR(COL),3,'0')
------------------------
001
005
011
111
```

Comment: :I got an idea after this answer.Thanks,I`ll implement n let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You can store as number and when you retrieve do as

```
select column1,to_char(column2,'00') from mytable
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2618c/1)